# python- printing from a file when s user asks for input

Tags: python

i have successfully been able to import the text file and store it in a dictionary.i want to be able to ask the user to enter the number he wants and print the values corresponding to the number the user wants. example the file contains 2 names 1: chris 2:sam... i want the program to ask the user for an inputand the user puts in 2 it should print sam from the dictionary.

here is my code:

```
file = open("songranks.txt","r")
d={}

#Repeat for each song in the text file
for line in file:

  #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the "," as a separator:
  fields = line.split(",")

  #and let's extract the data:
  songrank = fields[0]
  list =[fields[1],fields[2]]
  k = [str(x) for x in list]
  ["".join(k)]
  chris=len(k)-1
  k=k[0:chris]
  d[songrank]=k


#It is good practice to close the file at the end to free up resources
file.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this line `["".join(k)]` doing?

Comment: i didnt copy the code and yea ["".join(k)] was supposed to join strings in list =[fields[1],fields[2]]

Comment: But you haven't assigned it anywhere. Sorry i wasn't trying to be rude in anyway. Check if my answer help.

Comment: @donzion Please consider accepting some answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `input()` function to get user input and some changes below I suggest to make your program more compact and clear.
We should refrain from using variable name which matches the reserved keywords like `list`, `input`, `and`, `or` etc. that is why you should change variable `list` to some other name.

```
file = open("songranks.txt","r")
d={}

#Repeat for each song in the text file
for line in file:

  #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the "," as a separator:
  fields = line.split(",")

  #and let's extract the data:
  songrank = fields[0]
  li =[fields[1],fields[2]]
  k = ["".join(str(x)) for x in li][0]
  d[songrank]=k


#It is good practice to close the file at the end to free up resources
file.close()
# yes indeed it is good practice

get_track_id = input("Enter track id") # Ask for input
print(d[get_track_id]) # print the track name
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the input in python:

```
question = input('ask your question')
```

Then play with the answer stored as a string.
So from what you are saying something like:

```
print(d[int(question)])
```